# Is it possible to pass 2 variables with the same name like a conditional in ansible during runtime?

Tags: ansible

I would like to ask if it is possible to pass 2 variables with the same name as an --extra-vars parameter.
For example:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -e member=A -e member=B
```

It seems like it is possible with JSON but it did not yield the required result.

Using JSON, I tried the below but it seems to ignore the extra-var entirely.

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -e '{"member":["A","B"]}'
```

If I do the below, it simply accepts the first var and ignores the second

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -e "member=A or B"
```

The task looks like this:

```yaml
- name: Add a domain user/group to a domain group
  win_domain_group_membership:
    name: "{{ item.key }}"
    members: "{{ item.value }}"
    state: pure
  with_dict: "{{ varlist }}"
  when:
    - member is in item.value
```

and varlist is a list that looks like this:

```yaml
groupX: [ A ]
groupY: [ B ]
groupZ: [ A,C ]
```

So the purpose of me wanting to add two vars at runtime is when I don't want to go through the entire list and only target groups where "member" exists. As the list starts to grow, the intention is to add two/three members at a go rather than per member.

Comment: => ` ansible localhost -e '{"member": ["a", "b"]}' -m debug -a var=member`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    my_group_dict:
      groupX: [A]
      groupY: [B]
      groupZ: [A,C]

  tasks:
    - name: Print info for matching members
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Group {{ item.key }} with members {{ item.value }} matches at least one host in `members` extra var"
      loop: "{{ my_group_dict | dict2items }}"
      when: members | intersect(item.value) | length > 0
```

Calling with a correctly crafted json var as extra var gives the expected result:

```
$ ansible-playbook -e '{"members": ["A", "C"]}' test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Print info for matching members] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'groupX', 'value': ['A']}) => {
    "msg": "Group groupX with members ['A'] matches at least one host in `members` extra var"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'groupY', 'value': ['B']}) 
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'groupZ', 'value': ['A', 'C']}) => {
    "msg": "Group groupZ with members ['A', 'C'] matches at least one host in `members` extra var"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```